# Responsive design and content duplication issues

Tags: seo, responsive-design

i am working on responsive design site. I have a large navigation contained in one UL but want to turn it to two UL's on smaller screens. 
From a technical point of view using media query this is not pausing me a problem but means that the same links are twice in the source.
Also, on some of the pages we want to add a condensed content for the smaller screens, again, I could have the two variations of the content into two DIV's, with alsways one hidden depending on the device.

The question I have is about the search engines, I am guessing this would be seen as content duplication and could lead to penalties. What would be the best option then?

Answer (score 1):

**Repeat navigation 2 times will not create real problem**: even if Google do not ignore one of the navigations, will just mean that these links have a bit more of importante in your page.

But about **duplicate content**, this **is bad** for one aditional reason that is not just a possible SEO problem: you will serve two times same content, and will waste bandwidth. If this will be a real problem, maybe not if all time at least one have on CSS `display:none`, but **is a better idea if you try to think a way that with only CSS you can serve the same content for diferent display widths**.